# How do I parse XML and perform actions depending on the node contents?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an XML file which will output a string:

```
<mystring>
    <manipulate type="caps">
        <string>Hello There!</string>
        <repeat times="4">
            <string> FooBar</string>
        </repeat>
    </manipulate>
    <string>!</string>
</mystring>
```

The string I want this to create is:

```
HELLO THERE! FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR FOOBAR!
```

I would like to interpret the XML nodes and perform certain actions or output certain strings. I would like a clean way of doing this. This is just a simplified version and there will be other nodes with more complicated functions, but I need some help getting started.

I attempted to do it using Nokogiri but am struggling a little bit.

Comment: What problems in particular are you running into with Nnokogiri?

Comment: I don't really have any problems with Nokogiri, I can lookup nodes, their values and attributes, but I don't really know how to apply this to my situation. Its more of a ruby problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt, which uses recursion and map (I consider functional programming elegant :)

require 'nokogiri'

```
def build_string_from_xml(nodes)
  nodes.map { |node|
    inner_str = build_string_from_xml(node.xpath("./*"))
    case node.name
    when "string"
      node.content
    when "repeat"
      if node[:type] == "numbered"
        1.upto(node[:times].to_i).map { |i|
          inner_str + i.to_s
        }.join
      else
        inner_str * node[:times].to_i
      end
    when "manipulate"
      if node[:type] == "caps"
        inner_str.upcase
      else
        raise ArgumentError, "Don't know that manipulation type: %s" % node[:type]
      end
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Don't know that tag: %s" % node.name
    end
  }.join
end

doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(<<-XML)
<mystring>
  <manipulate type="caps">
    <string>Hello There!</string>
    <repeat times="4">
      <string> FooBar</string>
    </repeat>
    <string>!</string>
  </manipulate>

  <repeat times="3" type="numbered">
    <string> FooBar</string>
  </repeat>
</mystring>
XML

p build_string_from_xml(doc.xpath("//mystring/*"))
```

Comment: Hi Niklas. Thanks for that, its just what I was looking for. Just wondering how you would go about (using your code) to give each of the repeated strings a number based on what repeat it was. Output string to look like this... **Hello There! FooBar1 FooBar2 FooBar3 FooBar4!**

Comment: I added an alternative implementation for that task and also replaced inject with map in the original implementation because it looks a bit cleaner. Please don't incrementally add information about the question in the future, this is against the StackOverflow principles.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I have one more question that is very related to this, do I ask a new question altogether?

Comment: `nodes.map { |result, node|` should be `nodes.map { |node|`. You're passing in a NodeSet, which acts like an array of nodes.

Comment: @theTinMan: You are right, that happend when I changed from inject to map.
Nick: that's my final edit, please open a new question if can't go alone from here

Answer (score -1):

```
f = File.open("file.xml")
doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
f.close

result = []

doc.root.children.each do |node|
  if node.name == "string"
    result.push(node.inner_text)
    repeat = node.children[0]
    times = repeat["times"]
    for i in 1..times do
      result.append(repeat.inner_text)
    end
  end
  ...
end

" ".join(result)
```

Something like that. To be honest, I haven't used Nokogiri myself, but hopefully, this was helpful.

Comment: Rather than use `File.open` then close the file, look into using `File.read` or pass a block to `File.open` which closes it automatically.